# Zoomin to show details

Tags: objective-c

I have a view with some nodes( having textbox along with circle for everynode) having textview and images. There are around 20 nodes on one uiview( non scrollable) When user zoomin then it show all the details of the nodes that is subnodes and it should scroll also. 
I have used scrollview that will zoom but how do I reposition all the views as that will impact the position of every subview, image and textview.
Another option I have tried is i have taken two views

1) 1 view that is non scrollable

2) scrollable having view with all nodes and subnodes

This approach effect the performance. I want to show details like map on normal uiview

Please guide

Comment: Hey, can you provide more info about your view hierarchy and desired behavior. Should some views be added as user zoom in? Should they be deleted when user zoom out? Have you looked at viewForZooming(in scrollView:) and whether it is possible to react on this depending on scrollView.zoomScale?

Comment: its tree like structure with tables on each leaf. So want to show 2 levels and when user zoom in to get more details ( position get changed to everything to make space for more leafs) then other leafs should be visible. All leaves have text box to enter the text.
I have one view having tree and leafs and other one with all details. My idea was to replace the view with zoom in animation so that user should not know that view has been replaced
Please guide me if anything else can work out